# Wordpress PHP warning: Creating default object from empty value in wp-admin\includes\post.php on line 627

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Wordpress 4.2.2, Xampp installation in windows with PHP 5.6.8

I have added the following function to my theme's functions.php to automatically set the title of the post type 'departure':

```
function custom_title() {
    if ($_POST['post_type'] == 'departure') :
        $post_title = 'Departure-'.$_POST['post_ID'];
        return $post_title;
    endif;
    }
 add_filter ( 'title_save_pre', 'custom_title' );
```

Title setting for the custom post type "departure" works fine. But when I try to add a new wordpress standard post (i.e. post_type = post) I get the following error:

*Warning: Creating default object from empty value in wp-admin\includes\post.php on line 627*

Line 627 is as follows:

```
/**
 * Filter the default post content initially used in the "Write Post" form.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param string  $post_content Default post content.
 * @param WP_Post $post         Post object.
 */
$post->post_content = apply_filters( 'default_content', $post_content, $post );
```

All the other post types (i.e. custom types and wordpress standard page) work fine. By dumping $_POST data in a logfile I have seen, that for all the working post-types an empty array (i.e. array()) is passed as $_POST data. This does not happen with the "post" post type.

If I comment the function in functions.php, an empty array is sent as $_POST data when adding a new "post" post type, and the problem disappears.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return` a value, even if the post type isn't `departure`. The function should take an argument, and return something:

```
function custom_title($post_title) {
    if ($_POST['post_type'] == 'departure') {
        $post_title = 'Departure-'.$_POST['post_ID'];
    }
    return $post_title;
}
add_filter ( 'title_save_pre', 'custom_title' );
```

Comment: Thanks Mevius, it did solve the problem, Warning not shown anymore.

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question but... why does the function need an argument? and why it has to return "something"?

Are these specific function requirements for filter hooks described anywhere in the wordpress codex?

Comment: A filter function takes as input the unmodified data, and returns modified data (or in some cases, a null value to indicate the data should be deleted or disregarded). If the data is not modified by your filter, then the original data must be returned so that subsequent plugins can continue to modify the value if necessary. In other words, filters always require an argument, and must always return a value. More info [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters).